# Best way to expose IServiceCollection to test registrations?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, nunit

I am updating some old autofac code i have been using for a while now to test ioc registrations; to use it with MS builtin IOC container in aspnetcore. Some of newer apis are built in aspnetcore and do not use autofac.

Below is the sandbox I am playing with:

```
namespace GatewayProxy.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests : GivenTheNetCoreService<ITestReg>
    {
        private TestServer _server;
        private HttpClient _client;

        protected override void GivenThat()
        {
            _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
            _client = _server.CreateClient();
            base.GivenThat();
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Result.Should().BeOfType<TestReg>();
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public abstract class GivenTheNetCoreService<T> where T : class
    {
        private ServiceCollection _serviceCollection;
        public T Result { get; private set; }

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            GivenThat();

            When();
        }

        protected virtual void GivenThat()
        {
            _serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        }

        protected virtual void When()
        {
            using (var serviceProvider = _serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope())
            {
                Result = serviceProvider.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*In my startup.cs I have:*

```
private void IocRegistrations(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<ITestReg, TestReg>();
}
```

The `Result` property is null because the `ServiceProvider` is does not have any 'realized services' in it. So what is the best to test that `ITestReg` has been registered correctly?

Comment: I don't see where you register ITestReg? Do you want to test your Startup which registers that ITestReg or what exactly is your use case here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could access services by `server.Host.Services`.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var server = new TestServer(
                WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
    );
var testReg = server.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<ITestReg>();
var test = testReg.HelloWorld();
```

Comment: Ty - this worked but the code is ugly as hell  - need to refactor it somewhat.